# What field data do I need for the Green-Ampt infiltration Model?

Tags: hydrology, soil, agriculture, hydrogeology

I want to estimate infiltration in a soil. What kind of parameters should I be measuring in the field?

Comment: Please describe which resources you used to get familiar with this topic. Which parameters do you think should be measured?

Comment: @daniel.neumann Actually I am developing a model of influence of stage changes on water table in nearby aquifer. As the water table is also affected by recharge from rainfall in my case, so I want to know how much my water table is being affected by recharge from rainfall. I was just looking for different methods for this and came to know about Green-Ampt model.